# How to optimize an ajax call that spends most of its time in the Chrome "Request sent" category

Tags: ajax, performance, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, latency

I'm new to using Chrome's F12 developer tools. It's telling me that my ajax call is 4.2 seconds in the Request Sent part of the "Request/Response" section. I've also read that this part should take under a millisecond!

What does it mean and how can I fix it. This is a small ajax call and should take very little time unless latency to the remote server is where all the time is going.

[image]

Comment: Can you show what kind of Ajax call you're making? Is this a simple GET or a POST with payload? What happens and how long does it take when you do the same request via curl?

Comment: Also, please share your code, or even better. a public URL (if you have) so we dive deep into the code and see the full picture. It's a big question and small data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to 
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/profile/network-performance/resource-loading#resource-network-timing

Request sent time is the Request sending time and indicates how long it takes to send the request and should be much faster than this.

The latency could be caused by a slow network, busy server, long distance or a large request size.

I would begin by sending a ping to the server to check for a slow network or long distance (should be < 100ms typically) and then checking the request size (should be <100kb typically).

Comment: The exact issue I had was sending a large request. We are using asp .NET and the viewstate had a HUGE image object in it which was going back and forth in the form post - which the ajax call was making.